# A negative value for svg attribute <width> is not allowed

Tags: svg, visualization, treemap

I am trying to draw two google treemaps and keep them in tabs and am getting the error:

*A negative value for svg attribute `<width>` is not allowed*

Only one of the treemaps is visible. I am assuming the other one is not able to finish drawing. There is no other description of the error in the console. (Google chrome).

My code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tTqjr/

Comment: Have you checked for negative `weight` values already?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. I can draw both the treemaps if I remove the code which is trying to "tabify" them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved the problem. The div element on which Google Annotated timeline was being created had `display:none` property. Just made sure that `display:none` is changed to `display:block` before calling the draw function.

Comment: This has just solved the same issue with angularjs. Thanks!

Comment: I had a _google.visualization.PieChart_ in a div with CSS *border: 1px solid;* which was causing the same issue.
Removing it cured the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate this wasn't the OP's issue, but I had the same error, and setting `display: block;` didn't make any difference for me, but I had `padding-top: 50px;` on the div for the chart, and removing that resolved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped my two divs in a boostrap row/col pair to solve and togglke them with hide()/show()/toggle() buttons.

From

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="chart_div">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="chart_div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="chart_div">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="chart_div2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```